# How can I get Django Form ModelChoiceField values from Class View back to the template from which they came

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to display a list of tests, select one with ModelChoiceField Form and then display the selected test information on the same template the ModelChoiceField is on. (2 fields - the ID number and the name) as a link.  So basically you select the test, it appears under the ModelChoiceField as a link and then you click it go to a detail screen.  I can capture the selected choice information in the class view in form_valid but I don't know how to return to the template with this new information.  Tried various approaches with context etc. but nothing is working.

The screen will look something like this:
[image]

When you press the select button the test selected will appear on the same screen.  I need access to both the name and id number, which I get in form_valid

```
# forms.py
class TestBrowseForm(forms.Form):
    choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        Universal_Test_File.objects.all().order_by('test_name'), to_field_name="service_id")

# views.py
class ListTests(FormView):
    model = Universal_Test_File
    context_object_name = "testlist"
    form_class = TestBrowseForm
    template_name = "lab/list_tests.html"
    success_url = '/list_tests/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # choice is a queryset with both service_id and testname so we need to specify service_id
        choice = form.cleaned_data.get("choice")
        ## I want to display the test_name and link to service_id
        print(choice.service_id)
        print(choice.test_name)

        return super().form_valid(form)

#models.py

class Universal_Test_File(models.Model):
    service_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    specimen = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.test_name

#HTML
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 > 
           <form action="", method="post" novalidate>
               {% csrf_token %}
               {{form}}
 
                <div class="col m-5">        
                      <input type="submit" name="choice"/>
                </div>
            </form>
                    
               

                <div class="col-6"> 
                    <p class= mt-5>Select one or more tests using Shift and Control (Command on a Mac)</p>
                </div>
```

Comment: Django does not work on the fly itself. You need some JS, htmx, ajax or another js framework to make frontend changes without refreshing the site.

Comment: Thanks - I get that I will have to reload the page but I still need to get that info back to it on the re-render.  I can't seem to update Context and reload the page from form_valid, and I can't seem to access the choice variable from other methods.  I's still struggling with CBV's and this one is a stretch for me,

Answer (score 0):

I decided to take an entirely different approach since the one I was taken seems more suited to JS.